# How do I refer to the current tab name in a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook that has a lot of worksheet tabs that is used for tracking information relating to different site locations. Each site is assigned an Administrator, but the Administrator tied to the site is fluid and often changes around. For this reason the tab names use the name format [Initials]-[Site Name] and are frequently updated and reordered so people can find their sites on the list of tabs.

I have an Overview tab which collates certain tracked information from each of the sheets. It's a bit janky and hard to explain, but what it does is allow the site names to keep changing without affecting the data it's looking for across the table.

As you can imagine, if Site A changes from Administrator AA to Administrator ZZ, it goes to from AA-Site at the top of the table to ZZ-Site at the bottom of the table, but the data in the other columns won't follow it when that changes if I'm doing it with a simple ='Sheet Name'!A1 formula because the sheet name can change at any time and so it's looking for a sheet that no longer exists.

To avoid needing to make horrific nested IF statements that check for every possible Site/Administrator combination when searching for the data or needing to redo the formulas that find the tab names each time the Administrators change sites, what I've done is something along the lines of the below.

I'm using a formula to basically generate a worksheet name using the standard format we use for the tab names, and then a series of INDIRECT formulas to find the sheet tab that matches the name generated on the table, then pull from a cell inside that sheet (which doesn't move from sheet to sheet as they all have the same layout), so when I change the persons name, it still takes the correct data from the correct tab. What I'm doing is below. It's not an elegant solution but it has saved me a lot of headaches when I need to reorder or filter the table.

Formulas for Overview Table

| Administrator | Site Name | Site Tab Name | Number of Frogs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Persons Name | Sites Name | =IF([@[Administrator]]="John Smith","JS-"&[@[Site Name]], IF([@[Administrator]]="Jane Doe","JD-"&[@[Site Name]], IF([@[Administrator]]="Steve Stevenson","SS-"&[@[Site Name]] ...etc | =INDIRECT("'"&[@[Site Tab Name]]"'"&"!"&"A1") |

Results

| Administrator | Site Name | Site Tab Name | Number of Frogs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | London | JS-London | 14 |
| Jane Doe | Cambridge | JD-Cambridge | 1 |
| Steve Stevenson | Oxford | SS-Oxford | 9 |

Results after swapping John and Steves sites around

| Administrator | Site Name | Site Tab Name | Number of Frogs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Steve Stevenson | London | SS-London | 14 |
| Jane Doe | Cambridge | JD-Cambridge | 1 |
| John Smith | Oxford | JS-Oxford | 9 |

Each worksheet has a panel inside where I can paste an internal reference code and a link, which is then worked into a little hyperlink formula to combine them so Administrators can quickly get to our internal systems for that site and have the correct reference on hand. However I'm doing some "upgrades" to the general formatting of this section which will involve completely removing where they are at the moment and I will be needing to re-enter all of these references again one by one.

To save myself some problems I've "backed up" those references and links and such onto the Overview sheet by simply pulling them over using an INDIRECT formula then copy-pasting the values so they become "locked in", and I'm looking for a way to essentially call that information back with a formula inside each worksheet so that I don't have to go through all those tabs one by one pasting that information back into a new location. Finding a solution to this would also mean I can further compress where some information displayed on the worksheets is stored, helping with efficiency.

What I want to do is have a way to find the correct row on the Overview Table inside each of the worksheet tabs. Let's say I have 4 sheets for Overview, JS-London, JD-Cambridge and SS-Oxford. Inside the JS-London tab I want a formula that knows what the current sheets name is (which can be changed at any time) and finds the row inside the Overview Table that matches, then can pull data from that row back into the sheet, but when the sheet name changes it changes the row it's pulling from to keep matching the current sheets' name.

So for an example,

The Overview Table is as follows:

| Administrator | Site Name | Site Tab Name | Number of Frogs | Reference | Link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | London | JS-London | 14 | 01AA | Link 1 |
| Jane Doe | Cambridge | JD-Cambridge | 1 | 02BB | Link 2 |
| Steve Stevenson | Oxford | SS-Oxford | 9 | 03BB | Link 3 |

The Worksheet JS-London looks like this:

| Reference | Link | Number of Frogs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01AA | Link 1 | 14 |

The Administrators change their sites around, so now the Overview Table is as follows:

| Administrator | Site Name | Site Tab Name | Number of Frogs | Reference | Link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | London | JS-Oxford | 9 | 03BB | Link 3 |
| Jane Doe | Cambridge | JD-Cambridge | 1 | 02BB | Link 2 |
| Steve Stevenson | London | SS-London | 14 | 01AA | Link 1 |

The newly renamed SS-London worksheet still looks like this:

| Reference | Link | Number of Frogs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01AA | Link 1 | 14 |

The data the worksheet is searching for has moved from row 1 to row 3 on the Overview Tab, so it's following that data based on the current worksheet name.

I only know ways to pull data from the table either by using [@[Column Name]] or the cell reference. The problem with calling for the column name is I don't know how to then make sure it's finding the specific row with the worksheet tab name I want on it while keeping it fluid without doing a huge janky nested IF statement asking for all possibilities and results. The problem with the cell reference is as I mentioned before, if AA-Site becomes ZZ-site it moves from A1 to A26, so asking for the data in B1 after they move around is going to use the wrong reference numbers and I'm not sure it would self-update itself to follow the cell I want around.

I know there are ways to generate what the name of the current worksheet is into a formula such as using the CELL function, but I just don't understand how to work that into a live self-updating formula that then finds that string inside the Overview Table and then pulls over information from another column in that same table on the same row as the sheet name.

Ideally I want to avoid using VBA or scripts for this as it's an online worksheet updated by several people and I'm trying to keep it as efficient as this nonsense sheet can be where possible.

Comment: Why include the initials in the tab name?

Comment: Oh god, I'm so sorry for you... this is horrific and has so many unneeded repercussions... Just food for thought: Instead of locally optimizing a really shitty process, would it not be possible to alter the process and make everyone's lives easier? E.g., adding a table like "Jane's sites", "Marc's sites" to the overview page?

Comment: @P.b `Each site is assigned an Administrator, but the Administrator tied to the site is fluid and often changes around. For this reason the tab names use the name format [Initials]-[Site Name] and are frequently updated and reordered so people can find their sites on the list of tabs.` — They seem to use it as a makeshift tracking / assignment system

Comment: So the administrators don't know what site they're assigned to until opening this file?

Comment: Oh, sorry I thought you where the one asking the question to reply. @Roman I read that, but I question if that's really needed for the process and if not, why make it unnecessary complicated.